# VBA Copy a pivot table and rename

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on the following code in Excel VBA. I copied a pivot table to L8 and want to rename this pivot table to "PivotTable00". However error message "Object Doesn't support this property or method" when it goes to the second line here.

Is there a way to fix it? Many thanks.

```
wsPvtTbl.PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableRange2.Copy Destination:=wsPvtTbl.Range("L8")
wsPvtTbl.Range("L8").Activate
ActiveCell.pivotTable.Name = "PivotTable00"
```

Comment: you want to rename the original "PivotTable1" to "PivotTable00" ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `wsPvtTbl.Range("L8").Active` use `wsPvtTbl.Range("L8").Activate`

Comment: Doh!!  I didn't even see that!

Comment: Sorry this is a typo when I pasted my code here. My original code is just like what you corrected. Any help?

Comment: The code is correct, it will rename the pivot table in `Range("L8")` to `"PivotTable00"` without looking at the Pivot Table's previous name.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Activate` and `ActiveCell` (which only slows down your code's run-time), you can use the fact that the latest `PivotTable` that is pasted, gets the first index of the `PivotTables` in `wsPvtTbl` worksheet, try:

```
wsPvtTbl.PivotTables("PivotTable1").TableRange2.Copy Destination:=wsPvtTbl.Range("L8")
wsPvtTbl.PivotTables(1).Name = "PivotTable00"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. However PivotTable1 is my first table while I want to rename the second PTable. I think the pivot table will be named based on how many times it has been created so I don't know the number after PivotTable before change.